# How to store timestamp in Maven Surefire generated report.xml?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there a way, to instruct Maven Surefire, to save the test starting time of each JUnit Test Case in the report xml file?

I expect that the report should look a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="com.chris.testcases.Timestamp" time="1,962.965" tests="1" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
    <properties>
        <property ...>
    </properties>

    <testcase
      name="Timestampfilter"
      classname="com.chris.testcases.Timestamp"
      time="1,339.383"  <-- this is the already existing execution time
-->   timestamp="2015-03-11 16:44:05" /> <-- this is the NEW attribute I need
    ...
</testsuite>
```

*Background: I need this paramter for future processing in this xml, and just writing the timestamp in the "normal" logfile/output is no solution.*

I am using: Maven 3.2.5 with Surefire-Plugin 2.18.1.

Update: I found an similar question here: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-681

Comment: First i would suggest to create a [jira issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE) for this wish. Apart from that what is the purpose of having the start time written in there? And what kind of processing?

Comment: @khmarbaise: do you mean by "create a jira issue" that this feature is not supported in any way?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I'd like to match the timestamps to log file entries.

Comment: Ah...as far as i know it's currently not supported. You should vote on the issue you already referenced to bring some importance to it.